# Определить позицию элемента в массиве

Tags: javascript, массивы

Дано:

> Дан массив с числами. Найдите позицию первого числа 3 в этом массиве (считаем, что это число обязательно есть в массиве).

Проблема в том что я не могу определить позицию элемента в массиве.

Ниже мой код:

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

  if (arr[i] == 3) {
    console.log(arr[i]); // Что тут нужно,чтобы получить позицию в массиве?
    break;
  }
}
```

Огромное спасибо всем откликнувшимся;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы получить позицию в массиве, нужно ее вывести

```
...
  console.log(/*arr[*/i/*]*/);
  ...
```

Пожалуйста.

Comment: Супер!Спасибо огромное.

Comment: @Mitya Пожалуйста. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Позиция элемента в массиве - её индекс (в данном случае это i)

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

    if (arr[i] === 3) {
        console.log(i);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> я не могу определить позицию элемента в массиве

> Где можно посмотреть полный правильный код?

Такой вот вариант можно использовать...

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
const i = arr.indexOf(3)
console.log(i)
```